# How do event listeners work in Python's Turtle Module? And why are they non-blocking even though they are constantly listening in the background?

Tags: python, event-handling, python-turtle

In this piece of code, I've created a program using the Turtle Module for Python, which I heard was built with Tkinter. This working code will make the turtle say "Ah!" when you click on it, then teleport. What perplexes me the most is the t.onclick() method. How does it manage to keep listening for clicks on the turtle while allowing the rest of the code to run, unlike the input() function, which waits for the user to enter an input before proceeding?

Additionally, how does an event handler work in Python? Does it constantly check for clicks in the background with some sort of forever loop? Is there a mechanism that allows it to stay idle and somehow activate when a click is received? Or is there something else entirely that makes it work the way it does?

```
from turtle import *
from time import sleep
from random import randint

t = Turtle()
t.color("red")
t.penup()
t.shape("turtle")
t.speed(100)
t.points = 0

w = 200
h = 150

def rand_move():
    t.goto(randint(-w, w), randint(-h, h))

def catch(x, y):
    t.write("Ah!", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))
    t.points = t.points + 1
    rand_move()

t.onclick(catch)

while t.points < 3:
    sleep(1.5)
    rand_move()

t.write("WOW! You're good at catching me!", font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
t.hideturtle()
```

I have tried looking up the Turtle source code but failed to decipher it, and even googled quite a number of sites, but none seem to be specific enough to this question. Any help in clearing this up will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe part of what makes it hard to understand how turtle events work is this code which doesn't belong in a event-driven turtle program:

```
while t.points < 3:
    sleep(1.5)
    rand_move()
```

Instead, we should be handing off control to `mainloop()`, either explicitly, or, in some programing environments, implicitly.  Let's rewrite your code as an event-driven turtle program:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def rand_move():
    turtle.goto(randint(CURSOR_SIZE - WIDTH//2, WIDTH//2 - CURSOR_SIZE), randint(CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT//2 - CURSOR_SIZE))

    if turtle.points < 3:
        screen.ontimer(rand_move, 1000)  # delay in milliseconds
    else:
        turtle.home()
        turtle.write("WOW! You're good at catching me!", align='center', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
        turtle.hideturtle()

def catch(x, y):
    turtle.write("Ah!", font=('Arial', 14, 'normal'))
    turtle.points += 1

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.color('red')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()
turtle.onclick(catch)

turtle.points = 0  # user defined property

rand_move()

screen.mainloop()
```

> how does an event handler work in Python? Does it constantly check for
> clicks in the background with some sort of forever loop? Is there a
> mechanism that allows it to stay idle and somehow activate when a
> click is received?

This desciption isn't far off.  Turtle events fire from `mainloop()` which waits around for events to fire, such as mouse clicks, keyboard input, window closing, timer events, etc.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205497/5771269) for more information about `mainloop()` does in a turtle program.

The `onclick()` method only registers code for the main loop to call if/when a turtle-specific click comes in.  Just as `ontimer` registers code for the main loop to call some time in the future.  When we mix `while ...: sleep()` loops with turtle's main loop, we risk missing events during the sleep cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function is a Python built-in and not part of `tkinter`. The latter has its own `mainloop()` which normally handles all user input — unless its processing is interfered with by some function (such as `input()` or any long-running function). When that happens the GUI will "freeze".

Comment: Thank you for the further clarification, however after more reading, I still do not quite understand why I'm able to add more code after my t.onclick() line, as mainloop() is stated to be blocking.

Comment: `tkinter` supports being able to `bind()` many different kinds of user-input [`Event`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-types.html)s to user-defined "event-handler" functions. See [Events: responding to stimuli](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/events.html). The low-level details of this is done is mostly handled internally by the wrapped Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit I believe (which does whatever is needed on the various platforms it supports).